# How do you find a specific descendent from an element in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm automating the process of filling some forms online. The problem is that there are many individual elements whose children have basically the same ID of the stuff I want to find and fill. So my idea was to first find the parent I needed using `Selenium` and then go from there.

```
for range in cards:
  cardID = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'{cardis}/')]/ancestor::tr".format(cardis=allCards_NUMBER_List[range]))
  cardREG_PRICE = cardID.find_element(By.XPATH, "input[contains(id(), 'txt_preco_')]")
```

But when I run this it only said that it can't find `cardREG_PRICE`. The ID name is correct, and from what I've read the XPATH structure should work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not copy the element's xpath from the devtools inspect tab?

Comment: I'd have to do this for hundreds of elements in the form, so I wanted a way to deal with everything at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `xpath` is incorrect.That's why it is failing.
Instead of this

```
cardREG_PRICE = cardID.find_element(By.XPATH, "input[contains(id(), 'txt_preco_')]")
```

if should be like.

```
cardREG_PRICE = cardID.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//input[contains(@id, 'txt_preco_')]")
```

first thing `id` is an attribute and should pass with `@`, second thing `//` denote the node, Third thing `.` means intermediate child of the parent.

Comment: I tried this and this is what it gave me: `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression ".//input[contains(@id(), 'txt_preco_')]" is invalid: SyntaxError: Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression`

Comment: Copy my whole code. I can see still you have added @id() instead @id. Please check.

Comment: Remove () after @id